# jq update substring matched object

Tags: string, bash, jq

Json file:

```json
{
  "A": "jack",
  "B": [
    {
      "name": "jack/jil",
      "version": "0.1"
    },
    {
      "name": "went/well",
      "version": "1.2"
    }
  ]
}
```

now I need to update every objects version: "$version-dev" where name starts from `jack` while retaining rest of the json intact.

the closest I can get.

```
jq '.B[] |  select(.name|test("jack.")) | .version += "-dev"' old.json > new.json
```

in the above command I'm only getting the that particular object with updated value in the new.json but I need the whole json too.
any suggestions

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Cyrus please go to kids section if you need colorful images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put parantheses around the whole selection to be updated: `(… | .version) += …`

```sh
jq '(.B[] | select(.name|test("jack.")) | .version) += "-dev"' old.json > new.json
```

```json
{
  "A": "jack",
  "B": [
    {
      "name": "jack/jil",
      "version": "0.1-dev"
    },
    {
      "name": "went/well",
      "version": "1.2"
    }
  ]
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/3yiYsFxIVp)